# Instant::now() to &str

Tags: случайные-числа, rust

Как вывести значение из структуры Instant::now() в виде обычной строки?

```
use {
std::time::Instant,
};

println!("{}", Instant::now());
```

Comment: Похоже, что тебе нужно вот это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593387/how-can-i-get-the-current-time-in-milliseconds

Comment: @ozkriff Это показывает время в секундах с 1 января 1970 года, а `Instant::now()` с момента запуска операционной системы=) Если это написать на си то выглядит это `srand(GetTickCount());` знаю так же что можно проще написать `StdRng::seed_from_u64( unsafe { GetTickCount() }; )`, но зачем, когда есть это в самом Rust

Comment: нужно другим форматтером воспользоваться: println!("{:?}", Instant::now()); пример https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e3b7ec9a8f65d9b6a8e0ea70fb205b22

Comment: Если вопрос в том как получить сид для генератора случайных чисел, то для `Instant` реализован трейт `Hash`, который позволяет получить хэш содержимого структуры `Instant` в виде числа `u64`. Еще есть интересная структура `RandomState`. [Примеры](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0a7bddca8b992343c2e34c37c6197d0c)

Comment: @aSpex а можно ли этот hash преобразовать в u64 число? Я в целом хотел переписать функцию языка си: `srand(GetTickCount());`, которая после вызывается функцией `rand()` на язык Rust.

Comment: @ZerooneX метод [`Hasher::finish()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hasher.html#tymethod.finish) возвращает как раз `u64`. См. примеры по ссылке в моем предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: ЗЫ: вообще есть гораздо более надежные методы получения сида  - в крейте `rand`: [`SeedableRng::from_entropy()`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.3/rand/trait.SeedableRng.html#method.from_entropy)